# Plotting histograms in Python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I'm trying to create a histogram with two data sets overlying each other, however whenever I plot it using pandas.DataFrame.hist(), it creates two graphs:

[image]

The code is simply:

```
ratios.hist(bins = 100)
plt.show()
```

where ratios is just a DataFrame, 2 columns by about 7000 rows. Any idea on how to put the two graphs on the same axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [plot.hist](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#histograms) instead:

```
ratios = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal((1, 2), size=(100, 2)))
ratios.hist(bins=10)
```

This generates:

[image]

```
ratios.plot.hist(alpha=0.5, bins=10)
```

This, on the other hand, puts them on the same graph:

[image]