# How to make a histogram from all of the values in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, histogram

Suppose a dataframe like the one below:

```
a  b  c  d  e  f  g
b  0  0  1  2  0  5
c  1  3  2  0  2  5
d  12 0  0  1  3  9
e  3  4  7  8  9  0
f  0  0  0  0  1  1
g  3  4  4  5  1  0
```

I want to generate a histogram of the frequencies each value (on each cell) appears on the dataframe.

**Note that on my actual dataframe I have a matrix of 260 rows by 260 columns with values ranging from 0 to 30, including floating points.**

Any help would be extremely appreciated :)

Comment: `df.stack().hist()`

Comment: Is this not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/39529941/11301900 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotting histograms in Python using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39529941/plotting-histograms-in-python-using-pandas)

Comment: @AMC Completely different question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will make a histogram from all of the values:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [0,  0, 1, 2, 0, 5],
    [1,  3, 2, 0, 2, 5],
    [12, 0, 0, 1, 3, 9],
    [3,  4, 7, 8, 9, 0],
    [0,  0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    [3,  4, 4, 5, 1, 0],
])

plt.hist(df.to_numpy().flatten())
plt.show()
```

[image: histogram 1]

Alternatively you can use:

```
df.stack().hist(grid=False)
plt.show()
```

to get the exact same result.